# Next Palindrome SPOJ (PALIN)

Tags: c, palindrome

While solving the NEXT PALINDROME question on SPOJ. I have considered for every possible case and wrote the code. But it is showing WA(Wrong Answer). I am not getting my mistake or any possible case where my code won't work.
Below is my code.

Please help me out.

Thank You.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char K[10000000];
int a[10000000];
int main()
{
int t,length,i,count,j,rem,carry;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    scanf("%s",K);
    length=strlen(K);
    count=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        a[i]=K[i]-'0';
        if(a[i]==9)
            count++;
    }
    if(length==2 && count!=length)
    {
        if(a[0]<=a[1])
        {
            a[1]=++a[0];
        }
        else
        {
            a[1]=a[0];
        }
        for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        continue;
    }
    if(count==length)
    {
        if(length==1)
        {
            printf("11\n");
            continue;
        }
        memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
        a[0]=10;
        a[length-1]=1;
        for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        continue;
    }
    i=0;
    j=length-1;
    count=0;
    while(j-i!=1 && j-i!=0)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[j])
        {
            a[j--]=a[i++];
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a[i]<a[j])
                count--;
            a[j--]=a[i++];

        }

    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        rem=a[i]+1;
        a[i]=rem%10;
        a[j++]=a[i--];
        carry=rem/10;
        while(carry!=0)
        {
            rem=a[i]+1;
            a[i]=rem%10;
            a[j++]=a[i--];
            carry=rem/10;
            if(i<0&&j>length-1)
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(a[i]<a[j] || count<0)
        {
            rem=a[i]+1;
            a[i]=rem%10;
            a[j++]=a[i--];
            carry=rem/10;
            while(carry!=0)
            {
                rem=a[i]+1;
                a[i]=rem%10;
                a[j++]=a[i--];
                carry=rem/10;
                if(i<0&&j>length-1)
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
            a[j]=a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: If your code in not compiling: provide error message; if it is: provide input -output. P.S.: The last closing brace `}` before the `return` doesn't match any block or function.

Comment: you might want to explain what the actual question is?